# identifying the active image in Galleriffic

Tags: jquery, image, slideshow, html, addclass

After a question last night, I'm reworking a page into the scope of Galleriffic to take advantage of controlled image loading.. and to do so have to really get knitty gritty.

I'm having issues identifying the active image on the page. I've run through the plugin's functions back and forth so many times I'm going to cry. Literally just need to find a working CSS Selector so that I can make a variable out of it and manipulate that image.

Oddly enough- this plugin never adds a `.current` or `.active` class to the image being displayed.. So unfortunately I have to do this manually.

Anyway, I set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/PHSrE/) to demonstrate... All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @Evan said is correct. I've set up an example, you can modify the selector as you wish. Keep your eye on your javascript console.

http://jsfiddle.net/PHSrE/2/

Looking at the documentation I saw this event: `onSlideChange`

```
 onSlideChange: function(){
    console.log($('.image-wrapper').find('img'));
}
```

Comment: Planning on using that event to run oher dependent functions. Even so- the console is logging the image.. but I am unable to simply add a class to that image. http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/PHSrE/4/

Comment: @technopeasant It works, just not how we thought it would. It actually adds the class to the image right before it switches it out. So the event acts as more of a "onSlideOut" event. I tried `onTransitionIn` but it just broke the plugin...

Comment: jeesh, here I go. Going to deconstruct it and pull the features I need out of it so I dont have to deal with that B.S. been running into a fair amount of it. Thanks for your help. Although your answer wasn't exactly what I was looking for, it is correct, so I'm accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

there aren't multiple images on the page. so all you need to do is select the only image:

```
$("a.advance-link img")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find the selected thumbnail, if that helps:

```
$("div#flipbook-thumbs li.selected img")
```